# How does findViewById initialise a view

Tags: android

I just wrote an answer for someone confused by findViewById and I realised that I have a gap in my understanding.  This question is for knowledge and curiosity only.

Consider this:

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

`findViewById` returns an instance of `View`, which is then cast to the target class.  All good so far.

To setup the view, `findViewById` constructs an `AttributeSet` from the parameters in the associated XML declaration which it passes to the constructor of `View`.

We then cast the `View` instance to `Button`.

How does the `AttributeSet` get passed in turn to the `Button` constructor?

[EDIT]

So I was the confused one :).  The whole point is that when the layout is inflated, the view hierarchy already contains an instance of the view descendant class.  findViewById simply returns a reference to it.  Obvious when you think about it - doh..

Comment: +5 for the queston....because of your question I have researched and find the complete information regarding the basic flow....thanks to @Leonidos

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`findViewById` does nothing. It just looks through view hierarchy and returns reference to a view with requested `viewId`. `View` is already created and exists. If you do not call `findViewById` for some view nothing changes.

Views are inflated by `LayoutInflator`. When you call `setContentView` xml layout is parsed and view hierarchy is created.

attributes passed to Button's constructor by `LayoutInflater`. check [LayoutInflator source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#LayoutInflater.inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,android.view.ViewGroup,boolean%29).

Comment: Ah, I get it.  You mean in the view heirarchy, the referenced view is already instantiated by calling the ctor of the correct descendant class?

Comment: attributes passed to Button's constructor by layout inflater. check [LayoutInflarot source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#LayoutInflater.inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%2Cboolean%29).

Answer (score 6):

I don't think `findViewById()` constructs or instantiates a View. It will search in View hierarchy of already inflated layout, for a View with matching id.This method works differently for a `View` and for a `ViewGroup`.

from Android Source code:

`View.findViewById()` returns the same View object if this view has the given id or null, it calls:

```
protected View findViewTraversal(int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

`ViewGroup.findViewById()` iterates through child views and calls same method on these Views, it calls:

```
 protected View findViewTraversal(int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }

    final View[] where = mChildren;
    final int len = mChildrenCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        View v = where[i];

        if ((v.mPrivateFlags & IS_ROOT_NAMESPACE) == 0) {
            v = v.findViewById(id);

            if (v != null) {
                return v;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is mId, when I search in the view class mId is assigned to No_ID..where did it assign mId to the traversed View id

Comment: @Pragnani `mId` is view's assigned ID. when you/inflater call `setId(int id)` on a view, `mID` is set to supplied int value.